# Rewrite URL to plugin file

Tags: plugins, rewrite-rules, query-variable

I'm creating a plugin that handles courses from a 3rd party system, I've created a `add_rewrite_rule()` so the url `/course/32567` rewrites to `/wp-content/plugins/course-plugin/course-page.php?code=32567`

but the code= section doesn't get passed even though i've created a add_rewrite_tag()

```
add_action( 'init', function(){

add_rewrite_tag( '%code%', '[^a-zA-Z0-9_/]' );

add_rewrite_rule(
  '^course/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/?$',
  'wp-content/plugins/my-courses/course-page.php?code=$matches[1]',
  'top'
);

} );
```

and in the course-page.php file

```
<h1>COURSE: <?php echo $wp_query->query_vars['code']; ?></h1>
```

But it's displaying $wp_query->query_vars['code'] as $matches[1]

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Did you flush the rewrite rules?

Comment: Yep made sure i flushed them manually too

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the value of the result with the function  `var_dump` as follows:

`var_dump( $matches[1] );`

In this case, I think is returning an `Array` with the results you should try to out.

`<?php echo $matches[1][0] ; ?>`